# javascript weirdness with toFixed

Tags: javascript

Comparing floats. According to the fist block of code, 5 is greater than 37.66.   The second block claims that 5 is less than 37.66.  What is toFixed() doing to these that makes the first block react the way it does?  (This has only been tested on chrome in ubuntu)

```
amount = 5
total = 37.66
check = null
if(parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2) >= parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)){
    check = "amount IS GREATER"
}
```

check >> "amount IS GREATER"

```
amount = 5
total = 37.66
check = null
if(parseFloat(amount.toFixed(2)) >= parseFloat(total.toFixed(2))){
    check = "amount IS GREATER"
}
```

check >> null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`number.toFixed()` returns a string, so your comparison is not a numeric comparison.

This should work:

```
amount = 5;
total = 37.66;
check = null;
if(parseFloat(amount.toFixed(2)) >= parseFloat(total.toFixed(2))){
    check = "amount IS GREATER";
}
```

However, this is a somewhat strange way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.  How about this instead:

```
amount = 5;
total = 37.66;
check = null;
if( Math.round(amount * 100) > Math.round(total * 100)) {
    check = "amount IS GREATER";
}
```

edit: added semicolons

Comment: So "5.00" is greater than "37.66".  Is it an alphabetical comparisson?

Comment: Yup. '5' comes after '3', after all :)

Comment: Why did I think string comparisons were by length?  Been a long week I guess :-P

Comment: This is just another case of the crazy javascript type system allowing you to silently shoot yourself in the foot.  The fact that the comparison operators are overloaded for different types and that silent type conversion occurs in certain cases means that you always have to be very careful about the types you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is not correct since .toFixed will return a string, and a string being greater than the other doesn't make sense in this context